# No Data in audit for Accepted Shared Invitation event

Tags: sharepoint-online, audit-log-reports, microsoft

I have created a sharing invitation for an external user. and the user got an email and can able to access the site via link in mail. but I cant get an record in audit for the accepted sharing invitation activity.

My question is the audit don't return any data related to accepted sharing invitation, if possible then do mention the steps.

Thanks in advance.